# Deciding stability order between axial and equatorial positions in the following compound

Tags: organic-chemistry

I need to find the stability order between these two isomers -

[image]

From what I've learnt the presence of bulky group ($\ce{-OH}$) at equatorial position is favorable as it prevents steric clashes.

But here it's given that the second compound (with $\ce{-OH}$ at axial position) is more stable. I could not think of a reason why. Can you help me?

Comment: Hint: Hydrogen Bonding